# nonatomic and readonly property in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocoa, properties

A few times already I wanted to make a property, which is `nonatomic` and `readonly` at the same time.

This has the advantage that I can override the getter and check if an instance has already been created or not. And if not I can simply create it.

At the same time I can protect it from being overwritten.

---

### .h

```
@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) Foo *bar;
```

---

### .m

```
- (Foo *)bar {
    if (!_bar) {
        _bar = [[Foo alloc] init];
    }

    return _bar;
}
```

---

Whenever I do this, the compiler doesn't create an instance variable for me, so `_bar` doesn't exist.

Why? How can I create a `readonly` `nonatomic` property?

Comment: you may simply add Foo *bar; in to class interface or hide it in category `@interface SomeClass (){Foo *bar;}.......`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your property declaration is correct. I believe the problem here is that, because your property was declared as `readonly`, the compiler didn't automatically synthesize an underlying instance variable. The solution in this case is to synthesize one yourself using...

`@synthesize bar = _bar;`

Comment: Xcode synthesizes the properties automatically *only if* you don't provide the getter (and in the case of a readwrite property, also the setter) yourself. - This is the correct answer.

Comment: I believe it does not do it automatically when you declare your property as readonly.

Comment: Another option, instead of using `@synthesize`, is to declare the ivar yourself in the `@imlpementation` block.

Comment: Correct, you could also declare the instance variable in the `@implementation` block, but these days, I find that to be ugly and a waste of space. @Ramy Al Zuhouri, you are also half-correct. LLVM will auto synthesize (as of Xcode 4.4 I believe), but not in the case of `readonly` properties.

Comment: @MarkAdams: Xcode will also auto-synthesize a readonly property if you don't provide a getter method. The simple rule is: If you provide all necessary accessor methods, Xcode does not auto-synthesize.

Comment: @MarkAdams How is declaring the ivar any more "a waste of space" than adding the `@synthesize` line?

Comment: 1 line vs. 3? I'd call that a waste of space.

Comment: @MarkAdams I only need one line to declare an ivar. Maybe you are counting having the curly braces on their own lines. To each his own. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a private setter:

```
@interface YourClass()  // In the .m file 

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) Foo *bar;

@end
```

Then when assigning the variable:

```
self.bar = [[Foo alloc] init];
```

**EDIT**

Mark Adam's answer is also correct.

Comment: This is not correct. It is not necessary to create a private setter. - Also an ivar is by default __strong, therefore `_bar = [[Foo alloc] init]` *does* retain it.

Comment: No, you don't have to synthesize the property. That's one option. But you need to recant your statement about the object not being retained. That is simply not true as Martin stated.

Comment: `+alloc` returns a +1 retained object.  That is retained.

Answer (score 1):

In the implementation add @synthesize bar = _bar.